# How to perform a scroll in a drop down list to hidden element?

Tags: selenium, protractor, appium, ui-automation, appium-ios

How to perform a scroll in a drop down list with that format with selenium, appium ?
I'm using tag name to identify elements, `<md-option .../>` are the items in the drop down list.
[image]

Here is my html code :

[image]

Comment: Do you get any error while locating hidden element?

Comment: I meant by hidden not yet visible till scrolling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved it by this way :

```
// Create instance of Javascript executor
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
//Identify the WebElement which will appear after scrolling down
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("...."));
// now execute query which actually will scroll until that element is not appeared on page.
je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);
```

Comment: What if I don't know what the element is and I just want the combo box to scroll down to the end? Can I do that?

Comment: WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("....")); returns no results because the element has not yet appeared on the page, it will appear only after scrolling the dropdown scrollbar..

Answer (score 2):

Try following code.

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,0);').then(function () {
    page.saveButton.click();
})
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, i have already solve it with the below code